# Is there any solution for not a file URL problem?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I get this error while i run my application:

> {System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field due to: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Compression, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.

Any solution for this exception?

Comment: The error in your question doesn't seem to have any relation to the message in the the title.  Are you using System.IO.Compression your app, or a library that references it?

Comment: Yes!! We are using System.IO.Compression in our Project

Comment: have you tried using different linker settings?

Comment: We set only the Link Framework SDKs Only

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos